# Add text labels at the top of density plots to label the different groups

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-text

I have the following ggplot density plot

```r
ggplot(mpg, aes(cty)) + geom_density(aes(fill=factor(cyl)))
```

How do I remove the legend , and add labels above each distribution to denoted the group it belongs to?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [plot median values on top of a density distribution in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33960277/plot-median-values-on-top-of-a-density-distribution-in-ggplot2)

Comment: Removing the legend is easy: `ggplot()... + scale_fill_discrete(guide = F)`.  To add labels you'll need to calculate the x and y positions in advance

Comment: Not a dupe of that linked question, since that doesn't put the text at the peak of the density.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like it is said in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57381627/is-there-a-way-to-add-text-labels-at-the-top-of-density-plots-created-in-ggplot#comment101248134_57381627) by @DavidKlotz, the maxima of the densities of `cty` per groups of `cyl` must be computed beforehand. I will do this with Hadley Wickham's `split/lapply/combine` [strategy](https://vita.had.co.nz/papers/plyr.pdf).

```
sp <- split(mpg$cty, mpg$cyl)
a <- lapply(seq_along(sp), function(i){
  d <- density(sp[[i]])
  k <- which.max(d$y)
  data.frame(cyl = names(sp)[i], xmax = d$x[k], ymax = d$y[k])
})
a <- do.call(rbind, a)
```

Now the plot.

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(cty)) + 
  geom_density(aes(fill = factor(cyl)), alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_text(data = a, 
            aes(x = xmax, y = ymax, 
                label = cyl, vjust = -0.5)) +
  scale_fill_discrete(guide = FALSE)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is now a bit easier using the `geomtextpath` package:

```r
library(geomtextpath)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2

ggplot(mpg, aes(cty, fill=factor(cyl))) + 
  geom_density(alpha = 0.5) + 
  geom_textdensity(aes(label = cyl), 
                   hjust = "ymax", 
                   vjust = -0.5, text_only = TRUE, text_smoothing = 20) + 
  ylim(c(0, 0.6)) +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-01-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>