# How to label only the modal peak in a geom_col plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-col

I'd like to put a label above only the modal bar (the tallest peak) on my geom_col plot, giving the x-axis value (CAG). Here's an example, but I can only get it to label every peak.

```
x <- seq(-20, 20, by = .1)
y <- dnorm(x, mean = 5.0, sd = 1.0)
z <- data.frame(CAG = 1:401, height = y)
ggplot(z, aes(x=CAG, y=height)) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_text(aes(label = CAG))
```

I'd be very grateful for help with labelling only the top peak

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add text labels at the top of density plots to label the different groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57381627/add-text-labels-at-the-top-of-density-plots-to-label-the-different-groups)

Comment: Thanks, though the {split/lapply/combine} strategy seems to be for a {geom_density} plot, which only requires one variable, rather than the two variables required for {geom_col}. I've tried applying it to my data, with the initial line being {sp <- split(z$CAG, z$height), but get the error {need at least 2 points to select a bandwidth automatically}

Comment: I think I've solved this now with: a <- test %>% 
  group_by(SampleFileName) %>%
  filter(Height == max(Height))

Answer (score 5):

Just subset your dataset in `geom_text` to keep only the maximal value of y:

```r
ggplot(z, aes(x=CAG, y=height)) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_text(data = subset(z, y == max(y)), aes(label = CAG))
```

[image]

Comment: Great, thanks. However, my real data is grouped, using fill and colour, which I imagine is why it's not working on that. Could I please ask if there's a simple edit that can be made to the subsetting to make it work on grouped data?

Comment: @Mike see the question I pointed to above (which is a duplicate)

Comment: Thanks, though the {split/lapply/combine} strategy seems to be for a {geom_density} plot, which only requires one variable, rather than the two variables required for {geom_col}. I've tried applying it to my data, with the initial line being {sp <- split(z$CAG, z$height), but get the error {need at least 2 points to select a bandwidth automatically}